# jquery .load() only loads the first request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i will make it simple:

I have:

```
<a id="edit" data-link="mylink">Edit</a>
<a id="edit" data-link="mylink2">Edit2</a>
<div id="modal">

</div>

<script>
    $('#edit').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).data('link');
        $( "#modal" ).load( href );
    });
});
</script>
```

It works but only with the first button,not with the first request, only first button, it could be the 10th request and only the first button loads, the other ones dont load and i checked the links and the work.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique.

Comment: You should NEVER use the same ID twice on a page.  Those MUST be unique.   Reference:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.id

Answer (score 3):

[ID](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) of an element must be unique.

ID - attribute

> The id attribute specifies its element's unique identifier (ID). The
>   value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree
>   and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain
>   any space characters

Use class attribute to group similar elements

```
<a class="edit" data-link="mylink">Edit</a>
<a class="edit" data-link="mylink2">Edit2</a>
```

then use [class selctor](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
$('.edit').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).data('link');
        $( "#modal" ).load( href );
    });
});
```

When you use id-selector it will fetch the first element with the given id so your click handler gets registered only to the first link element

Answer (score 0):

```
<a **id="edit"** data-link="mylink">Edit</a>
<a **id="edit"** data-link="mylink2">Edit2</a>
```

Duplicate `id` here. ID must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

When you select using an ID selector, jQuery would return only one element because IDs must be unique on a page. Thus only one href is getting loaded. YOu must change your selector to a class Selector as follows. Note that the two links now have different IDs and have a common class. Multiple elements can have the same class and the jQuery selector will return all the elements with that particular class ("editLink" in this case)

```
<a id="edit1" class="editLink" data-link="mylink">Edit</a>
<a id="edit2" class="editLink" data-link="mylink2">Edit2</a>
<div id="modal">

</div>

<script>
    $('.editLink').click(function(){
        var href = $(this).data('link');
        $("#modal").load( href );
    });
});
</script>
```